# Missing: cordova-android@6.3.0

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, cordova-android

I am trying to fix 3 vulnerabilities in angular project and I am using `npm audit fix` command but it shows error like this

```
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-android@6.3.0
```

I am having alot of errors like some modules are installed.

Comment: Did you try to run 'npm install'? What's happened after it?

Comment: yes i tried but still it was coming but right now its resolved, I deleted the project and installed again. Thanks suggestion.